# How do I format moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm having trouble displaying my moment.js on my screen. I
m using the locale version. Here's what I have:

```
<h3 class ="time"><script type = "text/JavaScript">

     m.format("dddd MMM Mo YYYY");

</script></h3>
```

Comment: You forgot to identify the value of `m`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do something like this :-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- reference Moment.js library -->
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.7.0/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Moment Date</h2>
<!-- container for Moment.js output -->
<div id="displayMoment"></div>

   
<script type="text/javascript">
(function()
{
  // instantiate a moment object
  var NowMoment = moment();
  
  // display value of moment object in #displayMoment div
  
  var eDisplayMoment = document.getElementById('displayMoment');
  eDisplayMoment.innerHTML = NowMoment.format('YYYY-M-D');
  
})();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the moment output to someting

Perhaps you meant this

```js
document.querySelector(".time").textContent = moment().format("dddd MMM Mo YYYY");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>

<h3 class="time"></h3>
```